# Как сделать WebApp в телеграме через aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Хочу сделать форму для заполнения прямо в приложении телеграма. Мне надо чтобы клиент ввел все данные, нажал на кнопку отправить, и потом эти данные пришли боту, чтобы я мог с этим уже работать через aiogram. На чем сайт нужно писать? Только js + html как я понимаю, я хотел на fastapi написать, но чтобы оно работало мне нужно в github pages его положить, но как я понял тот же flask там не запускается, мне кажется с fastapi та же беда будет

Comment: вообще непонятно чего вы хотите добиться, какое имеет отношение сайт к телеграм боту? что значит форма в приложении телеграма, это в чате с ботом?

Comment: Это web app, я уже разобрался. Коротко говоря, web app - это полноценный сайт внутри телеграма, вот пример https://t.me/DurgerKingBot. В сайте добавляешь скрипт с тг, и потом, как результат кидаешь данные обратно в бота, и обрабатываешь их потом как хочешь. Почитайте - интересно на самом деле